# How to use Linq in React Js

Tags: reactjs, linq

How can i use linq in my react js?

i use to install linq and call it `import 'linqjs';`

and call it this way,

```
var Enumerable = require('linqjs');

Enumerable.From(wzones)
                        .OrderBy(function (x) {
                        return [x.Zone];
                    })      
                    .GroupBy("$.Zone", null,
                        function (key, g) {
                            let result = [
                                    'W'+key,
                                g.Sum("$.totalItemQuantity")
                            ]
                        return result; 
                    })
                    .ToArray()
```

below is my added wzones data. it seems im just having trouble importing linq in my react application. because it always says Enumarable is not a function.

```
{
    "Assignment": "36111",
    "Picklist": "PL00001361",
    "AssignmentStatus": "Passed",
    "Operator": null,
    "PickType": "1",
    "Zone": "1",
    "Region": 2.0,
    "startTime": "2018-03-12T08:56:35.01",
    "endTime": null,
    "createdDate": "2018-03-11T02:00:46.84",
    "totalItemQuantity": 137
},
{
    "Assignment": "37041",
    "Picklist": "PL00001370",
    "AssignmentStatus": "Processing",
    "Operator": "jrpsaladaga",
    "PickType": "1",
    "Zone": "4",
    "Region": 2.0,
    "startTime": "2018-03-12T18:51:05.01",
    "endTime": null,
    "createdDate": "2018-03-12T16:15:46.21",
    "totalItemQuantity": 196
},
{
    "Assignment": "37042",
    "Picklist": "PL00001370",
    "AssignmentStatus": "New",
    "Operator": null,
    "PickType": "2",
    "Zone": "4",
    "Region": 2.0,
    "startTime": null,
    "endTime": null,
    "createdDate": "2018-03-12T16:15:46.25",
    "totalItemQuantity": 1265
},
```

Comment: So, isnt it working now?

Comment: yes it throws me an error saying Enumerable is not a function.

Comment: can you post your wzones data?

Comment: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmGjaR Its working fine here

Comment: i updated my question with wzones details.

Comment: Check this link, https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmGjaR  I hope its working here with your wzones details

Comment: it still give me an error sir. i wonder why linq give me an undefined data where when i debug it it returns an array of data. this line `Enumerable.From(wzones)` here give me an error.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166791/discussion-between-g-s-and-jydon-mah).

Answer (score 5):

**1. Install linq**

```
npm install linq
```

**2. Import linq**

```
import linq from "linq";
```

**3. Use linq**

```
const q = linq
  .range(1, 10)
  .select(function(i) {
    return i * 10;
  })
  .toArray();
console.log(q);
```